# Let's $1,2,3,\cdots,2005,2006,2007,2009,2012,2016,\cdots$ a sequence of integers defined by :

Tags: sequences-and-series, divisibility

Let's $1,2,3,\cdots,2005,2006,2007,2009,2012,2016,\cdots$ a sequence of integers defined by :

$ x_{k}=k$         if    $1\leq k\leq 2006$

And

$ x_{k+1}=x_{k}+x_{k-2005}$ if $k\geq 2006 $

Prove that : this sequence has $2005$  consecutive terms each one is divisible by $2006$

I tried to use some elementary ideas but it doesn't work i would like to have a help

Comment: OP: Please verify that the text is correct since it has been edited several times.

Comment: @NoChance it's correct dear

Comment: I don't believe you. $2016\neq 2006.$

Comment: I've edited your question , Actually the sequence is defined by $1,2,\cdots,2006,2007,2009,2012,2016$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : show that the sequence modulo $2006$ is periodic for some period $T$, then compute the first few thousands terms $x_T, x_{T-1}, x_{T-2},\ldots$ modulo $2006$.

Comment: I don't really understnd

Comment: What is $x_0,x_{-1},...$